# spring jdbc template returns an empty result

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have the following code

```
resultList = daoResources.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, selectParams, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(resultClass));
```

SQL when run with the selectParams against database, I get result. The selecting fields name of the sql matches with the fields in the resultClass too. But for above code, I get an empty resultList.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: are u getting any compile time error/ warning or any exception during runtime... plz also post the code where u initialize your jdbctemplate  object...

Comment: no error.this code exist in a common location for all database access of such kind.only for this sql, I get empty result.That is what is confusing me.

Comment: check out the return values in BeanPropertyRowMapper . Maybe mapping is the issue here . Check this out via the debugger as @Pangea suggests .

Answer (score 3):

Debugging is your friend in this scenario. I suggest you enable debug logs for jdbc template to see what sql's and bind parameters are sent to database. Below is from the [3.0.x reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate)

> All SQL issued by this class is logged at the DEBUG level under the
>   category corresponding to the fully qualified class name of the
>   template instance (typically JdbcTemplate, but it may be different if
>   you are using a custom subclass of the JdbcTemplate class).